# Redis went down and took our app with it. How to mitigate this in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

Today our Heroku hosted app had a meltdown which meant our company couldn't access or use any of our internal tools. This was worrisome to say the least.

After much debugging, it turned out to be Redis that had crashed due to an AWS server crash in the UK... fun times. We only use Redis for actioncable so it seemed really odd that a simple crash of one connected tool would take down an entire app.

Has anyone had an issue like this before and know of a way to mitigate this in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the club :)
There are some strategies to prevent such situation in the future:

1. in general you need to implement Circuit Breaking pattern over your redis-client.

Implementation depends on your application architecture, and it's hard to say use this - it will match yours design at 100%.

In a nutshell: you describe rules, which are controlling when all trafic to Redis is not issued at all. Like: 10 connect fails during 30 seconds.
When this happens traffic will not be opened, but checks will happen after a while to see if Redis is back or not, and as soon as back - traffic will be sent to the redis.

2. Use Redis Sentinel or Redis Cluster (both are required to be supported by your redis client). In that case you've some failover mode - read more on Redis site.